# Similar alternative to extraction/insertion operator overloading in C# that exists in C++

Tags: c#, packet

I'm currently working on a Packet class for a C# project.

In my C++ version of my Packet class, I have extraction and insertion operators so a packet with multiple integers/strings/etc can be built in as few lines as possible like so.

```
std::shared_ptr<Packet> p = std::make_shared<Packet>(PacketType::Test); //Create packet of type (Test)
*p << 3 << "John" << "Hates" << "Susan"; //append data to packet
myConn.SendPacket(p); //queue packet to be sent
```

I am trying to figure out if there is a way I could get similar functionality in C# or if I will really be forced to have a separate line for each piece of data being fed to/extracted from the packet.

In C# I am imagining the equivalent will look something like this...

```
Packet p = new Packet(PacketType::Test); //Create packet of type (Test)
p.Append(3); 
p.Append("John"); 
p.Append("Hates");
p.Append("Susan");
myConn.SendPacket(p); //queue packet to be sent
```

Is there any way I can cut down on lines of code while not negatively impacting performance? I am not looking to fill the data into a string. I want it to stay as binary data.

Comment: Use some random string of characters as a delimiter, and then split the string once it is received.

Comment: I specifically put that I am not looking to fill the data into a string. I want it to stay as binary data. Thanks for the suggestion however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your `Append` method like below:

```
public void Append(params object[] args)
{
    // todo: save your args here
}
```

`params` keyword will allow you to add as many arguments as you want (just like in `printf` function). Usage is:

```
Packet p = new Packet(PacketType::Test); //Create packet of type (Test)
p.Append(3, "John", "Hates", "Susan");
myConn.SendPacket(p); //queue packet to be sent
```

Comment: And, as a added bonus, you can look at the type of each argument (say a string, a character, an integer, whatever) and handle each type individually in your Append function.  The recent addition of the "pattern matching" switch statement to C# (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) makes this easier.